# How to load images in custom listview and showing progress bar while doind this in Android?

Tags: android

I read a lot of threads here and elsewhere about loading images in custom listviews but I got nowhere! So, I thought I'd better ask!

The sittuation is as follows:

I have an activity that has a listview on it with 6 items (lets say Item1, Item2 etc). When the user clicks on an item I launch a new activity with another listview but this time the list view is a custom one with an image and some text.

The first activity's onCreate method is this:

```
GetImageFromURL eventImageLoader = new GetImageFromURL(FirstActivity.this, eventMultimediaID);
eventImageLoader.execute();

try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, R.id.textView1, eventName, bitmap);
eventList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.secEventList);
eventList.setAdapter(adapter);
eventList.setOnItemClickListener(eventNameListClickListener);
```

I create and start an AsyncTask to load the images into a bitmap List.

eventMultimediaID is a String array and so is eventName.

The GetImageFromURL Task is this:

```
public class GetImageFromURL extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Bitmap>>
{
private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
private Context callingContext = null;
private List<Bitmap> bitmap = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
private String[] eventMultimediaID = null;

public GetImageFromURL(Context callingContext, String[] eventMultimediaID)
{
    this.callingContext = callingContext;
    this.eventMultimediaID = eventMultimediaID;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(callingContext, "Loading Events", "Retrieving data from server, please wait...", true);
}

@Override
protected List<Bitmap> doInBackground(Void... params)
{       
    try
    {
        int length = eventMultimediaID.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            URL imageUrl = new URL("https://www.blahblah/servlet?blahblah=" + eventMultimediaID[i]);
            bitmap.add(i, BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUrl.openConnection().getInputStream()));
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bitmap;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Bitmap> bitmap)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < bitmap.size(); i++)
    {
        ShowEventCategory.bitmap.add(i, bitmap.get(i));
    }

    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

and this is the CustomAdapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
private Context currentContext;
private String[] data;
private List<Bitmap> evImage;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects, List<Bitmap> bitmap)
{
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.currentContext = context;
    this.data = objects;
    this.evImage = bitmap;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{       
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) currentContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View eventListItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_event_category_list_item, parent, false);

    ImageView eventListItemImage = (ImageView) eventListItem.findViewById(R.id.eventImage);
    TextView eventListItemText = (TextView) eventListItem.findViewById(R.id.eventText);

    eventListItemText.setText(data[position]);
    eventListItemImage.setImageBitmap(evImage.get(position));

    return eventListItem;
}
}
```

What I tried to do was to call the async task from the Activity to load the images and while doing so display a loading dialog. After the loading is complete the dialog is dismissed and the adapter takes the filled Bitmap array.

This doesn't work. After the Task is started the execution goes on (I think thats what SHOULD happen) and the adapter gets an empty array so I get an OutOfBoundsException. That's why I placed Thread.sleep(5000) in the main thread to wait for the load operation to complete. But of course that's not an acceptable solution!

:( Any suggetions?! I've spent all day on that thing!!!!
Thanx a lot in advance!

Comment: Try creating and setting your adapter in `onPostExecute(...)` of the `AsyncTask`. And you're right - using `Thread.sleep(...)` on the main thread is NOT acceptable. `Thread.sleep(...)` is a hack at any time but blocking the main thread of an Android app risks an ANR problem.

Comment: Thanx for the response! If I do create and set my adapter in the onPostExecute method a lot of variables and methods from the main Activity aren't going to be visible to call. I can make them static but is this a good practice?! Thanx again!

Comment: Have you defined your `AsyncTask` as an `inner` class of the `Activity`? If you do it that way, then it will be able to access all of the variables and methods from the `onPostExecute(...)` method.

Comment: My AsyncTask is in a separate class. I'll bring it in the Activity as an inner class to test it that way! Thanx!

Comment: FINALLY!!!!!!!!!!! Thanx a lot man you can't imagine how I feel now!! Cheers!!!